# Unable to display an image in the canvas from Axios response

Tags: javascript, blob, fabricjs

I was trying to display an image using canvas from Axios response.
Response I'm getting

```
{
    "data": "����\u0000...",
    "status": 200,
}
```

dataSlice.ts

```
try {
      const response = await Services.get('/datasetImages/239', { type: 'blob' });
      const blob = new Blob([ response.data ], { type: "image/jpeg" });
      return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
```

`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`
is creating a URL and was using same URL in canvas but the url doesn't contain any image.

Panel.tsx
 `const image = fabric.Image.fromURL(options.backgroundImage);` //Here, options.backgroundImage would be the image URL

Comment: no need to create blob anymore, the return result is `Blob` already